# Mongodb and Express

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to implement related data concept in MongoDB. I have one collection for user and one collection for posts. Now posts collection has created_by which refers to users collection. However I am unable to retrieve related data. Below are some of the schema I have.

```
{   "posts"
        {
            created_by:{ type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
            created_at:{ type:Date,default:Date.now },
            text:String
        }
}
{
       "users"
         {
             username:String,
             password:String,
             created_at:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi user3894192, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you describe in a bit more detail what you mean about not being able to retrieve the related data? It would help if you could show us some examples of the data in the database, and an example of the combined data you would like to query for. Also, you do need to show what you have tried so far, and describe what isn't working (e.g. by printing the query output).

Comment: Use `mongoose`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html elaborates with a very nice example. I have extracted the gist here for you

```
{
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

}
```

so you now have two models story and person where story refers person via the _creator field.

now to populate the _creator while querying through story you do the following:

```
{

Story
.findOne({ title: 'Once upon a timex.' })
.populate('_creator')
.exec(function (err, story) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('The creator is %s', story._creator.name);
  // prints "The creator is Aaron"
});
}
```

but you also need to make sure that you have saved the records properly in order to retrieve it properly. while saving you just need to assign the _id. see below.

```
{
var aaron = new Person({ _id: 0, name: 'Aaron', age: 100 });

aaron.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  var story1 = new Story({
    title: "Once upon a timex.",
    _creator: aaron._id    // assign the _id from the person
  });

  story1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // thats it!
  });
});

}
```

Comment: great. glad i was able to help. Can you please accept my answer.