# Saving one-to-many relationships in Mongoose both sides

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am very new to MongoDB and am using Mongoose.

I have two models: `users` and `recipes`.

`User`:

```
recipes: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'recipes'
}],
```

`Recipe`:

```
_creator: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    childPath: "recipes"
},
```

When I try to save a recipe and I assign the user to a recipe:

```
var recipe = new models.Recipe({
        title: req.body.title,
        slug: req.body.slug,
        _creator: user._id
    });

    recipe.save();
```

The recipe gets saved just fine (*even though I am not able to do recipe._creator.name to get the user name from the recipe*). But if I try to get the user details, the `recipes` array is empty. I would expect that it was filled with the newly created recipe reference. Why is it not?

Comment: _I am not able to do `recipe._creator.name`_ you should be able, anyway noSql databases dont use relations, it's more of a nested documents, definitely you have better way to write models

Comment: I have set up my models the same way it is described on this mongoose page http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html but I am not quite getting how to save them in a way that i can access "relationships" from both sides

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly one creator has many recipes. right ?
in that case your creator should recipes should reference have a reference to creator that's it.

if you examine closely in recipes you are doing a ref on recipes itself

```
{ recipes: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'recipes'
}],

}
```

instead you should do

```
{
    { recipes: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    }],
}
```

why in your user model you have a reference to user itself ? that seems not right.

check for an example i posted on [Mongodb and Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413030/mongodb-and-express/39416315#39416315)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your example:

`var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});`

is exactly like mine, it's just that instead of stories, i have recipes which ref to the recipe schema :)

Comment: are you saving the user object before saving the recipe ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what I had done to resolve this was updating both documents with the corresponding reference

```js
var recipe = new models.Recipe({
  title: req.body.title,
  slug: req.body.slug,
  _creator: user._id
});

recipe.save((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  user.recipes.push(recipe);
  user.save();
});
```